# How can I convert Long from String in scala

Tags: scala

I know I can parse from `Long` from `String` like the following

```
"60".toLong
```

or convert `Long` from `Double` like the following

```
60.0.toLong
```

or convert `Long` from a `String` of `Double` like the following

```
"60.0".toDouble.toLong
```

However, I can't do the following

```
"60.0".toLong
```

So my question is whether using `.toDouble.toLong` is a best practice, or should I use something like `try ... catch ...`?

Meanwhile, there is another question, when I try to convert a very large `Long` to `Double`, there maybe some precision loss, I want to know how to fix that?

```
"9223372036854775800.31415926535827932".toDouble.toLong
```

Comment: look at BigInt and maybe using toFloat first

Comment: `toFloat` is going to make things worse because the precision of `Float` is less than `Double`

Comment: @Tim I thought he was doing "60.0" , wasn't consdering precision then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap the operation in a `Try` anyway, in case the string is not valid.

What you do inside the `Try` depends on whether `"60.0"` is a valid value in your application.

If it is valid, use the two-step conversion.

```
Try("60.0".toDouble.toLong) // => Success(60)
```

If it is not valid, use the one-step version.

```
Try("60.0".toLong) // => Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException...)
```

---

Answer to updated question:

`9223372036854775800.31415926535827932` is outside the range for a `Double`, so you need `BigDecimal` for that.

```
Try(BigDecimal("9223372036854775800.31415926535827932").toLong)
```

However you are very close to maximum value for `Long`, so if the numbers really are that large I suggest avoiding `Long` and using `BigDecimal` and `BigInt`.

```
Try(BigDecimal("9223372036854775800.31415926535827932").toBigInt)
```

Note that `toLong` will not fail if the `BigDecimal` is too large, it just gives the wrong value.

Comment: Seems that `"9223372036854775800.31415926535827932".toDouble.toLong` may have precision loss because it can actually be converted as `9223372036854775800`. Can you fix that?

Comment: `"9223372036854775800.31415926535827932".takeWhile(_.isDigit).toLong`